# Running into issues with PyOpenGL and PyQt5 on OSX

Tags: python, macos, graphics, pyqt5, pyopengl

I'm taking intro to computer graphics this semester, currently getting into using PyOpenGL and PyQt5 to explore barycentric coordinates. My classmates using Windows machines are able to run the following code with no issues right out of the box, yet all of us on OSX are running into the same issues. I'm hoping someone else out there with more experience with this kind of environment might have an idea how we can solve these issues; we've all done plenty of googling already, with no results. Thanks!

Code:

```
    import sys
    from array           import array
    from ctypes          import c_void_p
    from OpenGL.GL       import *
    from OpenGL.GLU      import *
    from PyQt5.QtGui     import QImage, qRgb
    from PyQt5.QtOpenGL  import QGLWidget
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    from textwrap        import dedent


    # create a function that draws a triangle via software rasterization
    def softwareRasterization(width, height, vertices, colors):
        image = QImage(width, height, QImage.Format_RGB32)
        # TODO: compute the bounding box around the given vertices
        # TODO: compute the barycentric coordinates for each point in the box
        # TODO: color the points that are inside of the triangle
        if image.save("triangle.jpg", None, 100):
            print("Output triangle.jpg")
        else:
            print("Unable to save triangle.jpg")


    # extend QGLWidget to draw a triangle via hardware rasterization
    class HardwareRasterizationWidget(QGLWidget):

        def __init__(self, vertices, colors, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.vertices = array('f')
            # TODO: convert the input coordinate to normalized device coordinates
            self.colors = array('f', colors)


        def _sizeof(self, a):
            return a.itemsize * len(a)


        def initializeGL(self):

            verticesSize = self._sizeof(self.vertices)

            # create a new Vertex Array Object on the GPU which saves the attribute
            # layout of our vertices
            vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
            glBindVertexArray(vao)

            # create a buffer on the GPU for position and color data
            dataBuffer = glGenBuffers(1)

            # upload the data to the GPU, storing it in the buffer we just created
            # TODO: upload the color data into the GPU buffer as well
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataBuffer)
            glBufferData(
                GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                verticesSize,
                None,
                GL_STATIC_DRAW
            )
            glBufferSubData(
                GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                0,
                verticesSize,
                self.vertices.tostring()
            )

            # load our vertex and fragment shaders into a program object on the GPU
            program = self.loadShaders()

            # bind the attribute "position" (defined in our vertex shader) to the
            # currently bound buffer object, which contains our position data
            # this information is stored in our vertex array object
            position = glGetAttribLocation(program, 'position')
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(position)
            glVertexAttribPointer(
                position,
                3,
                GL_FLOAT,
                GL_FALSE,
                0,
                c_void_p(0)
            )

            # TODO: bind the attribute "color" to the buffer object


        def loadShaders(self):
            # create a GL Program Object
            program = glCreateProgram()

            # vertex shader
            # TODO: add a color input and color output
            vs_source = dedent("""
                #version 330
                in vec3 position;
                void main()
                {
                   gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
                }\
            """)
            vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
            glShaderSource(vs, vs_source)
            glCompileShader(vs)
            glAttachShader(program, vs)
            if glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) != GL_TRUE:
                raise RuntimeError(glGetShaderInfoLog(vs))

            # fragment shader
            # TODO: add a color input with the same name as the vertex output
            fs_source = dedent("""
                #version 330
                void main()
                {
                   gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                }\
            """)
            fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
            glShaderSource(fs, fs_source)
            glCompileShader(fs)
            glAttachShader(program, fs)
            if glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) != GL_TRUE:
                raise RuntimeError(glGetShaderInfoLog(fs))

            # use the program
            glLinkProgram(program)
            glUseProgram(program)

            return program


        def paintGL(self):
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)


        def resizeGL(self, width, height):
            glViewport(0, 0, width, height)



    if __name__ == "__main__":

        width = 640
        height = 480

        # TODO: prompt the user for 3 points and colors separated by spaces
        # TODO: validate input and parse into the vertices and colors lists

        vertices = [
            50, 50, 0,    # vertice 1
            600, 20, 0,   # vertice 2
            300, 400, 0   # vertice 3
        ]
        colors = [
            1, 0, 0,  # color 1
            0, 1, 0,  # color 2
            0, 0, 1   # color 3
        ]

        softwareRasterization(width, height, vertices, colors)

        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        w = HardwareRasterizationWidget(vertices, colors)
        pRatio = w.devicePixelRatio()
        w.resize(width/pRatio, height/pRatio)
        w.show()

        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/JesseRichmond/vEnvPyCharm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenGL/latebind.py", line 41, in __call__
return self._finalCall( *args, **named )
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/JesseRichmond/Desktop/Spring 2017 Academics/Projects/310/rasterization.py", line 45, in initializeGL
vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
File "/Users/JesseRichmond/vEnvPyCharm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenGL/latebind.py", line 45, in __call__
return self._finalCall( *args, **named )
File "/Users/JesseRichmond/vEnvPyCharm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenGL/wrapper.py", line 657, in wrapperCall
result = wrappedOperation( *cArguments )
File "/Users/JesseRichmond/vEnvPyCharm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/baseplatform.py", line 407, in __call__
self.__name__, self.__name__,
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glGenVertexArrays, check for bool(glGenVertexArrays) before calling
```

Comment: Just a hunch since I do not have a mac but can you check the OpenGL version for your app's context? You can do this by printing out the contents of `glGetString(GL_VERSION);`. I know that some OSes like OSX can be picky and require you to specify the OpenGL major and minor versions for your app to create the appropriate context, or they will default to a legacy context like 2.1. I think this might be the case here since `glGenVertexArrays` is an OpenGL 3.0 function after all...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Having trouble even printing result of `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` though.

I get `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)` error even in a small debug program where I import * from OpenGL.GL.

Comment: Where are you putting the `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` call? Have you tried placing it within your `paintGL` function? Also, interestingly I finally installed Qt and PyQt5 and when I run your code (on windows 10), I just get a black screen and an empty `triangle.jpg` file written to my hard drive...

Comment: Yes, that is what should be happening. The code runs fine for all my classmates using Windows - it's incomplete because it's a starter program written by the prof. I'll try putting the getString function in paintGL when I get back to my computer.

Comment: You might also want to check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42326036/2588654) on stackoverflow (same/similar problem you are having) as well as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25710446/2588654) on another question where they show how to force the OpenGL core profile in PyQT if you have not seen these already. I personally have only used PyOpenGL through PyGame and PySDL2 so I could not tell you too much about PyQT unfortunately. This is definitely a context setting-up issue though rather than an OpenGL one!